# Конвертация строки в Mongo BSON ObjectId?

Tags: php, yii2, mongodb, php7

В базе хранится значение в виде Mongo BSON ObjectId("5a500d59f796314bd969fda6"). Оттуда оно попадает в форму на сайте и автоматически преобразуется в строку. Из формы обратной связи оно тоже приходит в виде строки вида "5a500d59f796314bd969fda6".
А мне нужно сохранить его в виде BSON ObjectId и никак не могу понять как обратно конвертировать,
так не работает: MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID('5a500d59f796314bd969fda6')
Прошу помочь.

MongoDB extension version   1.2.3

Yii Version 2.0.11.2

yiisoft/yii2-mongodb    2.1.4.0

PHP Version 7.0.22-0 ubuntu0.17.04.1

Answer (score 0):

решил так: new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID('5a500d59f796314bd969fda6')